# Is it possible to remove Webpack from a project?

Tags: webpack

I'm not talking about versions or anything like that.  I want to remove Webpack from project I took over.  It is creating more headaches than it is worth.  I have searched everywhere and cannot find a way to remove it from my project.

What do I have to take out besides webpack.config.js and the webpack dependencies in the build?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove it without using another bundler?

Comment: I never thought of that.  Is there something easier to use than webpack (there has to be , nothing else can be this complicated).  Having said that, I would have to remove webpack in order to add a different one (suggestions welcome).

Comment: Parcel might be a good choice